# SQL PIVOT group by 2 columns

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, pivot-table

I have a attendance table as below i want group them by time and section,status is **null** mean that the employee is absent :

[image]

Any idea how to generate output like below?

[image]

my current code :

```
SELECT TIME,COUNT(SECTION) AS SECTION,COUNT(STATUS) AS COUNT 
FROM attendance_record
GROUP BY TIME,SECTION
ORDER BY TIME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TIME, SECTION, COUNT(*) as TOTAL,
       COUNT(STATUS) AS IN, ( COUNT(*) - COUNT(STATUS) ) as ABSENT
FROM attendance_record
GROUP BY TIME, SECTION
ORDER BY TIME
```